# MIDI support for HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: html, audio, midi

Can we play a MIDI using HTML5 audio tag?

I see a lot of javascript midi player/editors etc. but I haven't found a very basic player (play, stop, pause...) that supports easily a midi player.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

see example of MIDI-player here
https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midiplayer.html

Click 'source' to open GitHub project

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are 3 supported file formats for the  element: MP3, Wav, and Ogg

[More about that here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

Comment: So there is no alternavite... I don't know why is so difficult to get a very basic player for a midi file, I don't get it...

Comment: @Ulrira You and me both.  If you read on the developer message boards for browsers, you quickly get a sense of indifference related towards media in general, unless it's powering YouTube or something.  There is also a large knowledge gap... browser developers simply don't get it in general.